# Returns nil if I scroll tableView fast

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, cell

Trying to load images in `tableView` asynchronously in (Xcode 9 and Swift 4) and seems I have a correct way but my code stops working if I scroll my `tableView` fast. So basically I had **found nil error**.
Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell


    let feed = feeds[indexPath.row]

    cell.titleLabel.text = feed.title
    cell.pubDateLabel.text = feed.date
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = nil

    if let image = cache.object(forKey: indexPath.row as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        cell.thumbnailImageView?.image = image
    } else {

        let imageStringURL = feed.imageUrl

        guard let url = URL(string: imageStringURL) else { fatalError("there is no correct url") }

        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (url, response, error) in

            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { fatalError("can't create image") }

                    let updateCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell // fast scroll issue line

                    updateCell.thumbnailImageView.image = image
                    self.cache.setObject(image, forKey: indexPath.row as AnyObject)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have issue on the line:

```
let updateCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
```

If I scroll down slowly everything works just fine and no mistakes appear.

Does anyone know where I've made a mistake?

Comment: Why you dont delete that line, change updateCell to cell, return a placeholder cell in which the user can see it is loading and add a completion handler which will change the image of the cell after it has downloaded?

Comment: @J.Doe that line checks if cell is visible or not as I understand because If I will not use that line I see how images changes all the time while they find appropriate image to display.

Comment: I think you should use prepareForReuse function on the CustomTablieViewCell. And set the image back to nil.

Comment: I don't know if there is any specific reason to not use one of libs 
(Alamofire-Image)[https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage]
(Kingfisher)[https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher]
just set with url and a placeholder

Comment: @mihatel just truing to understand basics

Comment: @cb89 but why it is depend on speed of scrolling?

Comment: Well this is lika a retain cycle. Your calling cellForAtIndexPath in the row where you are setting up the TableViewCell. Seems like your loading the image twice, if the image isn't cached until u scroll to the postion again

Comment: @cb89 tried you solution but no result.

Comment: Do it inside your cell. Create a `url` property and just change it in this method. The cell then should track the changes of the property and possibly trigger a new load. Also, in the completion handler you should be checking that the `url` is still the same as the one you are loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may happens if cell you are trying to get using `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` is not visible currently.
To avoid crash you can use optionals as:

```
let updateCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell // fast scroll issue line
updateCell?.thumbnailImageView.image = image
```

Keep everything as it is, I hope it should work without any errors.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think that here may be any problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider one of popular UIImage extension libs, like I said in comment for example [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) and set thumbnail with the placeholder, as soon as image will be ready it will be replaced automatically.

One more thing I change no need to have updateCell I removed it.

Please add placeholder image and test it should work, sorry I didn't fully check syntax.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell


let feed = feeds[indexPath.row]

if let image = cache.object(forKey: indexPath.row as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
    cell.thumbnailImageView?.image = image
} else {

    let imageStringURL = feed.imageUrl

    guard let url = URL(string: imageStringURL) else { fatalError("there is no correct url") }


    cell.thumbnailImageView.af_setImage(withURL : url, placeholderImage: <your_placeholderImage>)


return cell
```

}

Comment: I can do it with different libraries but I wanted to find my own mistake to see what I understand wrong.